# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at m.$scope.profile

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a child service function in Main Controller.

But I am getting error on `than` in profile function.
This is my profile function inside main controller.

```
App.controller("globalCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope, $window, $location, $rootScope, $cookieStore, toastr, ClientService,) {
  var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};

  $scope.profile = function(theClient) {

              var getCurrentClient = theClient;
              var getOrganizationId = $rootScope.globalSession.OrganizationId;    
            if($rootScope.globalSession.UserRole == "Admin")
             {          
               if (getOrganizationId) {       

               ClientService.getClient(getOrganizationId).then(function(aGetClientResponse) {

                if(getClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_SUCCESS) {

                        $scope.myprofile = getClientResponse[1];
                        $location.path("/profile");
                }
                else { 
                    toastr.warning($scope.USER_MESSAGE.SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, '');
                 }
              });
            }
          }
      };
)};
```

This is Service of another controller whom function "**getClient**" I am calling in profile function.

```
App.factory('ClientService', function($http, $cookieStore, uuid2, API_URL, REQUEST_HEADER, RESPONSE_CODE) {
    var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};

    return {

        getClient: function() {

            if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
                //API Call
                var promise = $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER).then(
                function(aGetClientResponse) { //Success Callback

                    return [aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse.Result.ResponseCode, aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse];
                },
                function(aGetClientResponse) { //Error Callback
                    return [aGetClientResponse.status,''];
                });
            }
            return promise;
        },
        setClient: function(aClient) {
            theClient = aClient;
            $cookieStore.put('UserData', theClient);
        }
    }
});
```

Need Help. cant figure out the Problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a syntax error in the first line `ClientService,`, is that a typo? If yes to which line the error is pointing to?

Comment: where is error their is not any error

Comment: there will not be a ',' in the first line of your code after `clientService`. It should be a typing mistake. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service to just return a `promise` and handle that promise in your controller using `then`

The service directly returns API call, **no `then` in `service`**

```
var promise = $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER)
```

**Here is your service:**

```
App.factory('ClientService', function($http, $cookieStore, uuid2, API_URL, REQUEST_HEADER, RESPONSE_CODE, $q) {
    var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};

    return {

        getClient: function() {

            if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
                var promise = $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER)
            }
        else {
             var promise =  $q.reject();
        }
            return promise;
        },
        setClient: function(aClient) {
            theClient = aClient;
            $cookieStore.put('UserData', theClient);
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the controller handles the **success and failure** `response` using `then`

```
ClientService.getClient(getOrganizationId).then(function(){},function(){})
```

**Here is your controller, observe `then`**

```
App.controller("globalCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope, $window, $location, $cookieStore, toastr, ClientService) {
  var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};

  $scope.profile = function(theClient) {

              var getCurrentClient = theClient;
              var getOrganizationId = $rootScope.globalSession.OrganizationId;    
            if($rootScope.globalSession.UserRole == "Admin")
             {          
               if (getOrganizationId) {       

               ClientService.getClient(getOrganizationId).then(function(aGetClientResponse) {
               var response = [aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse.Result.ResponseCode, aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse];

                if(response[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_SUCCESS) {

                        $scope.myprofile = response[1];
                        $location.path("/profile");
                }
                else { 
                    toastr.warning($scope.USER_MESSAGE.SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, '');
                 }
              },
                function(aGetClientResponse) { //Error Callback
                    return [aGetClientResponse.status,''];
                });
            }
          }
      };
)};
```

Comment: I think the code is not going to `if block`. pls check my updated answer.

Comment: Now I get error over here in controller  function(aGetClientResponse) { //Error Callback
                    return [aGetClientResponse.status,''];

Comment: yes since we are returning empty response, status will be undefined, change the second function to `function(aGetClientResponse) { console.log('error occured)    });`

Comment: obviously now log is printed.

Comment: so, now atleast the error is not coming right? the issue is  `var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};` this condition is failing `if(theClient.OrganizationId)`

Comment: Yes I get that. In profile function If I set this variable as  var getOrganizationId = getCurrentClient.OrganizationId;   instead of getOrganizationId = $rootScope.globalSession.OrganizationId; then I dont get the value of organizationId and I dont know why. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139368/discussion-between-sravan-and-miki-jay).

Comment: @Sraven I have sent message you in our discussion chat.

Comment: @MikiJay, yes you can use the session storage, for your requirement. I will help you on it if you needed.

Comment: In List I also get the session I changed it the way we did for login but still  I am getting  Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at b.$scope.getClientList

Comment: Also when I refresh I redirect to login page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it this works, but instead of returning a object with the functions inside, have you tried to declare them as part of the factory object? I have some declared like this and they are working, so have a try:

```
App.factory('ClientService', function($http, $cookieStore, uuid2, API_URL, REQUEST_HEADER, RESPONSE_CODE) {
    var theClient = $cookieStore.get('UserData') || {};

    var function = {
        getClient: function() {

            if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
                //API Call
                var promise = $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER).then(
                function(aGetClientResponse) { //Success Callback

                    return [aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse.Result.ResponseCode, aGetClientResponse.data.GetClientResponse];
                },
                function(aGetClientResponse) { //Error Callback
                    return [aGetClientResponse.status,''];
                });
            }
            return promise;
        },
        setClient: function(aClient) {
            theClient = aClient;
            $cookieStore.put('UserData', theClient);
        }
    }
    return function;
});
```

---

You can have a try with this too:

Define the services in the controller declaration (and remove one rootScope, its duplicated):

```
App.controller("globalCtrl", ['$scope','$rootScope','$window','$location','$cookieStore','toastr','ClientService', function($scope,$rootScope, $window, $location, $cookieStore, toastr, ClientService){
   [...]
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `getClient()` the code looks like this:

```
        if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
            //API Call
            var promise = ... some stuff ...;
        }
        return promise;
```

So if the condition is false you return `undefined` which doesn't have a `.then` property.

You should make sure that a function which returns a promise always returns a promise. If you want to signal that a missing id is an error then just return `$q.reject(something)` for an already rejected promise.

Comment: If I remove this condition then I get error inside http call parameter where it cannot find organizationId

Comment: Yes, so you have to create a different promise if the condition is false that resolves or rejects to whatever you want to use in the case where you can't send the request.

Comment: Sorry, no. I answered the question but this isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to ensure that there is always a `promise` object available.

```
getClient: function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
        //API Call
       $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER).then(
        function(aGetClientResponse) { //Success Callback
            deferred.resolve(aGetClientResponse);
        },
        function(aGetClientResponse) { //Error Callback
            deferred.resolve(aGetClientResponse);
        });
    }else{
        deferred.reject('Missing OrganizationId');
    }   

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Its ant-defer pattern.Not recommended

Answer (score 1):

In the else part you can return dummy promise with either resolve(`$q.resolve()`) or reject(`$q.reject()`) status.

JS :

```
getClient: function() {

            if(theClient.OrganizationId) {
                //API Call
                var promise = $http.get(API_URL.GET_CLIENT+theClient.OrganizationId+"&CorrelationId="+uuid2.newuuid()+"&ContextOrganizationId=009", REQUEST_HEADER).then(
                 ///your rest code
                return promise;
            }else{
                 return $q.reject();
            }

        }
```

With `$q.reject()` it will call error handler in profile call.So,add error handler callback as second parameter

```
ClientService.getClient(getOrganizationId).then(function(aGetClientResponse) {
//success code
},
function(){ //add it in your script

//check error here
});
```